# MySQL, merging specific row columns to another row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

can you help find a solution for this?

I have a this query

```
 SELECT P.id, P.url, PT.name, PT.lang
 FROM cms_pages P
 INNER JOIN cms_pages_translations PT
   ON PT.page_id = P.id
 ORDER BY P.id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

that returns something like this:

```
 ID |     URL        |       NAME       | LANGUAGE          
---------------------------------------------------
 1  |  'hello-word'  | 'Hello world'    | 1
---------------------------------------------------
 1  |  'hello-word'  | 'Hola mundo'     | 2
---------------------------------------------------
 1  |  'hello-word'  | 'Olá mundo'      | 3
---------------------------------------------------
 2  |  'now-online'  | 'We're online'   | 1
---------------------------------------------------
 2  |  'now-online'  | 'Estamos online' | 2
---------------------------------------------------
 2  |  'now-online'  | 'Estamos online' | 3
```

How can i achieve something that looks likes this:

```
 ID |     URL        |       NAME_1      |       NAME_2      |   NAME_3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |  'hello-word'  |  'Hello world'    |   'Hola mundo'    | 'Olá mundo'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2  |  'now-online'  | 'We're online'    | 'Estamos online'  | 'Estamos online'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is called `pivoting`.  If you know the maximum number of potential columns, you can use `conditional aggregation`.  If not, you'll have to use `dynamic sql`.  There are lots of examples on SO for both.

Comment: @sgeddes i already searched and it didnt help me that much, can you recommend me a good articles about those concepts?

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of languages?  Is it no more than 3 languages/columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of potential languages -- which would result in the knowing the number of extra columns -- you can use `conditional aggregation`.  Here's an example based off of your sample data:

```
select id, url, 
    max(case when language = 1 then name end) name_1,
    max(case when language = 2 then name end) name_2,
    max(case when language = 3 then name end) name_3
from <yourquery>
group by id, url
```

If you do not know the number of languages, you'll have to use `dynamic sql` to build your columns on the fly.